# Getting selected value from dropdown when editing aggregated object at MVC 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I can't get the value from `DropDownList` when the `DropDownList` targets a field of an object inside the Model.

```
@Html.DropDownList("MyID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The `ViewBag` is filled with this:

```
ViewBag.MyID = new SelectList(db.WFMasters, "MyID", "Code", wFDefDetail.wfDef.MyID); //MyID is property of wfDef. Model is wFDefDetail.
```

I have no trouble to get the value of the `DropDownList` if the target value is a property of the model.

In this case, the DropDownList is correctly filled but I don't get the selected value at the View Controller method. The controller receives `null` for `wFDefDetail.wfDef.MyID`.

Also, if I change to `@html.EditorFor` method I can get the value of `wFDefDetail.wfDef.MyID` so must be some detail I miss to put DropDownList to work too.

Comment: Do you want to send selected dropdown list item value from browser to controller or render select HTML element with selected item that specified in ViewBag?

Comment: i wan't to send the selected value from the browser to the controller.

Comment: Is your dropdown list a part of a form or a standalone control? Do you want to open new page or refresh existing page by AJAX?

Comment: It is inside the form. I only want to get the value. It is a regular use case except the model aggregates other objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To map data properly dropdown **name** property should match the model like below:

```
@Html.DropDownList("wfDef.MyID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.MyID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Using your code it throws an error saying that there is no item of this type at ViewData, but i got it from there.
If you wan't to complete i use :     `@Html.DropDownList("wFDefDetail.wfDef.MyID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.MyID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: Another thing i notice just now, the name can be only ´wfDef.MyID´, without the Model.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dropdown list [change event handler](https://api.jquery.com/change/) to send the form to your server. In the example below the request to your profile will be sent when the select control is changed. The selected option value will be sent with request as `tab` parameter.

```js
$("[name=tab]").change(function() {
  $(this).parent("form").submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="https://stackoverflow.com/users/2700303/byteartisan">
  <select name="tab">
    <option value="default" disabled="disabled">Select tab...</option>
    <option value="profile">Profile Tab</option>
    <option value="topactivity">Activity Tab</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

If the form includes single data field only, then you could get tab value in action method directly:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string tab)
{
    string SelectedValue = tab;
    // do something
}
```

If the form sends a complex data that described by custom class, use corresponding property of argument object, for example:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(CustomType FormData)
{
    string SelectedValue = FormData.tab;
    // do something
}
```

Comment: That will solve the problem, but i still think that MVC should support it, I may miss something. @html.EditorFor works, so it must be some detail. I will wait for a direct solution, before i accept it.